# Getting dates in one row

Tags: domo

I am working on the data visualizer and have the data as below

| order | Model | ord date | rec date | cur prm | prm date -7D | prm date -14 D | prm date -28 D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 6/7/2022 | 6/9/2022 | 6/9/2022 |  |  |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/31/2022 |  |  | 6/2/2022 |  |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/17/2022 |  |  |  | 6/2/2022 |

The columns order,model, ord date, rec date,cur prm come from the DOMO workbench while the columns prm date -7D, prm date -14 D, prm date -28 D come from the beast mode...

I am trying to get the above data in the format below...Can you please help here.

| order | Model | ord date | rec date 1 | rec date 2 | rec date 3 | cur prm | prm date -7D | prm date -14D | prm date -28D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B67189 | mcx2134 | 9/24/2021 | 5/17/2022 | 5/31/2022 | 6/7/2022 | 6/9/2022 | 6/9/2022 | 6/2/2022 | 6/2/2022 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the pivot and unpivot feature in Magic ETL. You will probably need to add your beast modes to the ETL as well before you use the pivot feature using the "Add Formula" tile:

Pivot/Unpivot: https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044951294-New-Magic-ETL-Tiles-Pivot

Add Formula: https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044258533-Writing-Formulas-in-the-New-Magic-ETL